# Downgrade from Office 365 to Office 2010

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010, office365

I need install an Office 2010 into a relative new laptop with Windows 10 (64 bits) with a basic Office 365 installed.

When I try to install Office 2010 SP 2, I get this error: "There are no products affected by this package installed on this system". Usually that means there is a newer version, so I can't install an older version.

[image]

Therefore I have tried to uninstall 365 and install 2010... but I'm getting the same error.

How can I install an Office 2010? I have thought in a virtual machine, but I'm afraid laptop can't run it.

Comment: Even if you manage to find an installer, you're not going to be able to authorise it. Microsoft no longer support 2010 at all, not even for phone activations.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd been wondering about that. Looks like some are having some success (see comments) by changing the date and time, but personally I wonder if it's worth the trouble: https://borncity.com/win/2021/07/29/microsoft-office-2010-keine-aktivierung-mehr/

Comment: Have you tried to use the Office Uninstall tool to cleanup your system, then after Office is uninstalled, try installing Office 2010?

Comment: @Ramhound Based on the screenshot, it really looks like that's the SP2 (only) installer, not the Office 2010 installer, so that can't go through since there's nothing to update.

Comment: @MetalMikester - I don't disagree.  However, running the uninstaller tool, will prepare the system to have Office 2010 installed.  It being unsupported is a separate problem.  I disagree that Office 2010 cannot be activated by phone.  You might not be able to get an installer for it but that's also a different problem.

Comment: Office2010 and Windows 10 are very unlikely to work together. Its not supported and is doomed to fail. Seriously, this is not the route you want to take. Install 2016 or higher if you want to work on Windows 10. Even though 2013 still works, microsoft is not supporting that either and I occasionally run into weird problems in 2013 that magically vanish when upgraded to a newer version such as 2016 or 2019.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, a good cleanup is a good idea. I saw on a Microsoft page that they don't do the activations anymore. Either way, personally I'd go for a newer version, especially on Windows 10.

Comment: Why do you specifically need Office 2010? Is there any reason you can't use something like LibreOffice?

Comment: Note: Office 2010 no longer gets security updates. So, it's fine to do this for retrocomputing purposes in a controlled environment, but please don't use it for work. Otherwise, you're setting your PC up to become a ransomware victim, a botnet drone or worse.

Comment: Also, speaking from experience, unless you were working with massive datasets in Excel, the 64bit versions of Office were not recommended by Microsoft until 2018, when Project and Powerpoint also showed benefits. If you need other 32bit addins, or certain VBA macros, then sticking with 32bit versions is still advised.

Comment: Rather than battle to make Microsoft's spyware do something it wasn't designed to do, and which might stop working at any moment, if you're able to manage with the less featureful but more amenable LibreOffice, you'll be in a stronger position.

Comment: Office 2010 beats Libre Office hands down any day. I still use it as my main office suite. Miles better than Office 365. That said, I mainly use it on Windows 7, not 10. Also, if you have a volume copy of Office, you are not beholden to Microsoft rendering your software useless. Security updates for O2010 only ended a couple months ago, so it's unlikely to be significantly more insecure than any Office at this moment.

Comment: @Herohtar and others, I need specifically Office 2010 because it is to prepare an official exam and MS Office 2010 is required version.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, it sounds like you're trying to install the service pack itself (not the full product), which is looking for a product to update (Office 2010), hence the error message.  You need the full Office 2010 installer (which may or may not include SP2, depending on how Microsoft packaged things).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on Microsoft page, there are instructions for installing Office 2010 64-bits in Windows 10:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/install-office-2010-1b8f3c9b-bdd2-4a4f-8c88-aa756546529d

But by the looks of the files in your screenshot, you are trying to install a Service Pack without Office 2010 already installed, hence the error.

The first step would be to get an Office 2010 installation disc, or installation files, and then follow the steps mentioned by Microsoft:

**Install 64-bit Office 2010**

What you need to know before installing 64-bit Office:

- You must be running 64-bit Windows. To check, see [Which Windows operating system am I running?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13443/windows-which-operating-system).
- Uninstall any 32-bit versions of Office. See [Uninstall or remove Office 2010](https://support.office.com/article/9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8#OfficeVerson=2010&OfficeVersion=2010).
- Make sure any 3rd-party Office add-ins that you rely on are stated as being Office 2010 and 64-bit compatible. Possible backward incompatibility is why, if in doubt, stay with the 32-bit version.

1. Insert the Office 2010 installation disc.
2. Click Start, > Computer, and right-click in the disc drive where the Office 2010 installation disc was inserted, and select Open.
3. Open the x64 folder in the installation root, and then double-click setup.exe.
4. Folder structure of platform chooser for Office 2010 64-bit install. After setup completes, continue by following the default installation instructions, by entering the product key (step 2).

Comment: Your answer consists for 2/3rd of copied material from a very generic "how to execute a setup from a CD in 2010". Format that quote as quote or don't post it at all.

Comment: Also, this material has probably been misunderstood here: It actually tells you "If you don't have a good reason to install a 64bit version, YOU DON'T." In the Office 2010 era, 64bit office was not mainstream.